# Elements not staying inside div (/w image background)

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/apswak/pen/qNQxgA

I'm trying to create a header with a background image. Why is every element I nest inside being pushed above the background image?
Is there a better way to do this?

```
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum random stoof</h1>
    <h3>Master.</h3>
  </div>

.header {
  background-color: #222;
  background: url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/825303XHAE.jpg')50% 100px no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

Comment: It seems to work if you remove `100px` from `background`.

Comment: thanks so much, that worked

Comment: you can also remove margin top as i explained in answer bellow @Kreitzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons:

1.) The background placement `50% 100px` pushed the background image 100px down. Just remove the 100px...

2.) The `margin-top: -50px;` on `.header`. Remove it or adjust it - depending on what you are after when you use it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRqQOr

P.S.: `filter: blur(1px);` will blur everything in `.header`, not just the background image (i.e. also the text). You might want to remove it...

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your CSS code. You have `margin-top:-50px;` which is pulling everything up for 50px. Remove that line or change it to some positive value and you will see changes!

```css
.header {
  background-color: #222;
  background: url('https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/825303XHAE.jpg')50% 100px no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum random stoof</h1>
    <h3>Master.</h3>
  </div>
```